# Laptop screen flickering

Tags: sony-vaio

My laptop screen shows up random black spots, what can be the cause? Its a sony vaio, NVdia graphics. Recently the screen has started flickering, that too randomly. please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most probably a hardware problem, and we can't help except for the usual banal suggestions of updating the display driver.

I would take this laptop to a qualified repairman, or if it's still under warranty then call it in. There is no miracle cure for such a problem.

Comment: thnx harrymc, i think taking it to the service cntr wud b btr cz updating the drivers didnt help.